# PHP require not traversing up directory on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4

This was working without issue but after running a system update on EC2, I noticed I was getting the following error and no matter what I do I can not resolve this. It just doesn't seem to move up a directory and tries to access '../../' as part of the file path rather than traversing up two directories.

**The file I am trying to require lives here**

```
/var/www/html/site/app/data/myFile.php
```

**My index file lives here: /var/www/html/site/public/rest/index.php**

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../app/data/myFile.php';
```

**The error**

**`Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/site/public/rest/../../app/data/myFile.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')`**

Comment: Are you troubleshooting the correct problem? What I mean by that: I'm speculating that the *message* doesn't show the resolved path, but the resolution is actually occurring when testing for the file, so the first question is... is the file actually present at `/var/www/html/site/app/data/myFile.php`, with correct permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't write a comment due to my reputation (1 pt) but probably the reasons are two:

1. Check if `require "/var/www/html/site/app/data/myFile.php";` works. If not, check if the owner of `/var/www/html/site/app/data` (and all of its content) is the user running the server web (run `top` and see the username corresponding to `apache2`, `apachectl` or `httpd`).
2. Try to execute `print __DIR__;` in order to check if it is correct and eventually follow this question posted on Stackoverlfow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654069/wrong-dir-magic-constant-value. It's ununaswered but has some interesting tips.

Comment: You should also check permissions on the path to myFile.php using something like "namei -mo /var/www/html/site/app/data/myFile.php". All components of the path must be traversable.

Comment: In his case `/var/www/html` has right permissions but probably `/var/www/html/app` and/or subdirectories and files don't.

Comment: I did a chmod 755 at the top level recursively, shouldn't this have fixed the issue?

Comment: How can I check ownership of the file etc like you mention in your first step?

Comment: Execute the command `ls -l /var/www/html/`. It will show you a list of files and directories with the respective user and group owners. Paste the output in your original question. Run `chown -R WEBUSERNAME /var/www/html/app` to recursively set the user running apache as the owner of `/var/www/html/app` (substitute WEBUSERNAME with the username that runs apache - usually it's called `www-data` or `httpd` or `www`).